# Windows.Identity in debug mode returns NT username, but returns NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM when published to server

Tags: c#, iis-7, windows-authentication, windows-identity

On the Visual Studio environment, during debugging I am retrieving the proper username through the familiar c# code line below:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

However when I publish the project to the Server on Windows 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5, it returns me NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

I have configured web.config to use 
    <authentication mode="Windows" />

Utilizing the Application Pool that is configured to use Integrated mode with Identity set to LocalSystem

And on the IIS for the virtual folder, I have disabled Anonymous Auth and set Enable to Windows Auth.

This is the first time that this company is being set for Microsoft development and hence struggling to set up the environment correctly.

What am I missing to get the code to work? OR perhaps, what is a better code that would return me the Window NY Authentication user? 
One more thing: If I hardcode the strUserName, the rest of the code to extract the User FullName works and works fine. So AD works.

Spent about a day or two to resolve this issue, any help will be appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

It's dangerous to run the Application Pool as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (aka LocalSystem). This means everything your code running in IIS has highest privileges in the system.
If you choose default IIS APPPOOL\Application Pool Name (aka ApplicationPoolIdentity), IIS impersonate appreciate account to process.

[image: Running ApplicaationPoolIdentity can impersonate local Administrator]
[image]

Comment: Will set it back to use ApplicationPoolIdentity and that it too returns back the Application Pool Name. What does and how to achieve your last statement : "IIS impersonate appreciate account to process"?

Comment: Please ensure "Windows Authentication" is enabled and "Anonymous Authentication" is disabled.

Comment: "And on the IIS for the virtual folder, I have disabled Anonymous Auth and set Enable to Windows Auth."

Comment: Added an image. If IIS_IUSRS have "secpol.msc -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Impersonate a client after authentication" privileges, Not only "System" could impersonate someone who logged on.

Comment: Running "Virtual Directory" not "Application" ? It has very limited configuration (Root Application rules all). Sites have same icon as I uploaded?

Comment: I checked this on my computer and it is exactly as your screen shot.

Comment: Adding below in web.config, still couldn't impersonate?

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />

    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Users"/>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>

Comment: Impersonation is not supported in IIS7+ in Integrated Pipeline Mode, this is because Integrated pipeline supports asynchronous pipelines, and with asynch pipelines an await can return on a different thread from the original thread, and since impersonation is a thread based context, this doesn't work.  However, you can disable the validation of this by setting `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>` but this may have repercussions so be careful that this is actually what you want to do.

Comment: The word "Impersonation" in classic ISAPI integration deprecated? Yes. But both classic and integrated pipeline actually use impersonation. (You can see what happened in Security event.) And original question, @IkramM. tried LocalSystem account. That's odd...

Answer (score 0):

Posting this SURPRISE answer as I was unable to find out the configuration; environment settings and/or code to determine what would be the best way to extract NT Auth User.  I ended up using the standard unconventional way, and gave up on why WindowsIdentity wouldn't work.

Went back to using this.  Its still using the App Pool with "Integrated" mode and Identity set to "ApplicationPoolIdentity"; and the site is set "Enabled" to only "Windows Authentication".  The below line works just fine and I got what I need.

```
Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"];
```

Comment: Did you have try following?

Context.User.Identity.Name
Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Comment: Yes and it is true.  When I look up the Authentication Type, it comes up with "Kerbose"?

Comment: If 'Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated' is true and Authentication Type is "Kerberos", its identity is authenticated by Active Directory, not environment variable "AUTH_USER" set by malicious user :)
Active Directory... based on LDAP uses Kerberos authentication, if not in AD environments, Context.User.Identity.AuthenticationType should "Negotiated" (means NTLM authentication). If you need about Kerberos authentication, I'll explain it.

Comment: If I hear you right, don't use AUTH_USER. Think the solution lies in making my company environment such that Context.User.Identity.AuthenticationType return "Negotiated", But how? yes please explain if you can steer me in setting it for Windows NT instead of Kerberos.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolved this problem. It is not beautiful, but it works

Add Attribute [CustomAuthorize] to my Action and add class to controller

```
 [CustomAuthorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           var http = this.HttpContext;
           String UserID = http.User.Identity.Name; 
            return View();
        }



  public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Project has property Windows Authentication Enabled. Managed Pipeline Mode Integrated.
IIS configuration for project Windows Authentication Enabled.
Application pool Integrated.

Hope it helps.